# C++でのTwitterクライアントプログラムのOAuth認証

Tags: c++, twitter, visual-c++

C++を利用してTwitterクライアントプログラムを開発したいです。
外部ライブラリはOpenSSL（暗号化）とcpprestsdk（HTTP通信）のみです。
OAuth認証も自分で実装しようと思うのですが、うまくいきません。
具体的にはシグネチャ？の作成とPOSTするデータ（パラメータ）の作成がうまく行っていないのかも...と思っています。

[Twicpps](https://soramimi.jp/twicpps/index.html)と[このサイト様](https://qiita.com/alpha_kai_NET/items/cdd3ec27a70a77e06c59)を参考にさせていただいているのですが、サイトだとHTTPリクエストヘッダに*Authorization*というヘッダを作り、そこにもOAuth認証情報を記載するとの事が書いてあるのですが、Twicppsのコードを見ているとそのようなことをしているようには見えません。
パラメータの作成は行っていますが、urlとパラメータだけを乗っけてPOSTしているようなコードです。

<s>以下のコード（.hpp）で通信はできるのですが、スターテスコード400で帰ってきて、レスポンスは以下のとおりです。</s>　(訂正：ツイートはできましたが、Authorizationヘッダが必要な通信が実装できません)

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

基本はTwicpps寄りで開発してきたのですが、*Authorization*をつけないと認証はできないようです。
以下のコード全文を載せます。cppの方はmain関数からtweet関数を呼び出しているだけですので掲載しません。
どこがおかしいのか指摘して頂けると光栄です。
よろしくおねがいします。

OS:Windows10 Home
IDE：Visual Studio 2019 Community
OpenSSL:OpenSSL-Win32 1.0.2r
cpprestsdk:cpprestsdk v141

```
[Header.hpp]

#pragma once

#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <winstring.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
#include <time.h>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"libeay32.lib") 

using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

#define REST_POST_PATH "C:\\ProgramData\\System72\\CAIOS\\CAIOS\\REST_POST_RESPONSE.json"
#define REST_GET_PATH "C:\\ProgramData\\System72\\CAIOS\\CAIOS\\REST_GET_RESPONSE.json"
#define TWITTER_URL "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"

typedef enum {
    POST,
    GET
} METHOD;

enum CodePageID : unsigned int {
    ANSI = CP_ACP,  // ANSI
    OEM = CP_OEMCP, // OEM(依存)
    MAC = CP_MACCP, // MAC
    UTF7 = CP_UTF7, // UTF-7
    UTF8 = CP_UTF8  // UTF-8
};

struct Request {
    string url;
    string post;
};

struct TwitterAPI_Keys {
    string Consumer_Key = "ここにキーを代入";
    string Consumer_Sec = "ここにキーを代入";
    string Accesstoken = "ここにキーを代入";
    string Accesstoken_Aec = "ここにキーを代入";
};

namespace CAIOS {

    namespace String {

        static string UTF8_to_SJIS(string message) {
            int n;
            wchar_t ucs2[1000];
            char utf8[1000];
            n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, message.c_str(), message.size(), ucs2, 1000);
            n = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ucs2, n, utf8, 1000, 0, 0);
            return std::string(utf8, n);
        }

        static string SJIS_to_UTF8(std::string const& message)      {
            int n;
            wchar_t ucs2[1000];
            char utf8[1000];
            n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, message.c_str(), message.size(), ucs2, 1000);
            n = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, ucs2, n, utf8, 1000, 0, 0);
            return std::string(utf8, n);
        }

        // string から wstring 変換
        static wstring StringToWString(const string& refSrc, unsigned int codePage = CodePageID::ANSI) {
            vector<wchar_t> buffer(MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0));
            MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, &buffer.front(), buffer.size());
            return wstring(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
        }

        // wstring から string 変換
        static string WStringToString(const wstring& refSrc, unsigned int codePage = CodePageID::OEM) {
            vector<char> buffer(WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr));
            WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, &buffer.front(), buffer.size(), nullptr, nullptr);
            return string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
        }

        static string EraseString(string str, string erase) {
            for (size_t c = str.find_first_of(erase); c != string::npos; c = c = str.find_first_of(erase)) {
                str.erase(c, 1);
            }
            return str;
        }
    }

    namespace REST {

        static string GET(Request req) {
            try {
                using namespace CAIOS::String;

                http_client client(StringToWString(req.url));

                cout << " -> HTTP request mode [POST]" << endl;
                cout << " -> HTTP request to " << req.url << endl;

                auto response = client.request(methods::GET).get();
                auto str = response.extract_string();

                cout << " -> Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << '.' << endl;
                cout << " -> Content length is " << response.headers().content_length() << " bytes.\n" << endl;

                ofstream ofs(REST_POST_PATH);
                ofs << WStringToString(str.get().c_str()) << endl;
                ofs.close();

                return WStringToString(str.get().c_str());
            }
            catch (...) {
                cout << "HTTP通信中に例外が発生しました　[GET]" << endl;
            }
        }

        static string POST(Request req) {
            try {
                using namespace CAIOS::String;

                http_client client(StringToWString(req.url));

                http_request request(methods::POST);

                cout << " -> HTTP request mode [POST]" << endl;
                cout << " -> HTTP request to " << req.url << endl;

                char body[3000];
                sprintf_s(body, 3000, "Authorization: OAuth %s", req.post);

                request.headers().add(L"Content-Type", L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.set_body((wchar_t*)body);

                auto response = client.request(request).get();
                auto str = response.extract_string();

                cout << " -> Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << '.' << endl;
                cout << " -> Content length is " << response.headers().content_length() << " bytes.\n" << endl;

                ofstream ofs(REST_POST_PATH);
                ofs << WStringToString(str.get().c_str()) << endl;
                ofs.close();

                return WStringToString(str.get().c_str());
            }
            catch (...) {
                cout << "HTTP通信中に例外が発生しました　[POST]" << endl;
            }
        }

        static string URL_encode(string str) {
            const int NUM_BEGIN_UTF8 = 48;
            const int CAPITAL_BEGIN_UTF8 = 65;
            const int LOWER_BEGIN_UTF8 = 97;

            int charCode = -1;
            string encoded;
            stringstream out;

            for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
                charCode = (int)(unsigned char)str[i];

                //エンコードする必要の無い文字の判定
                if ((NUM_BEGIN_UTF8 <= charCode && charCode <= NUM_BEGIN_UTF8 + 9)
                    || (CAPITAL_BEGIN_UTF8 <= charCode && charCode <= CAPITAL_BEGIN_UTF8 + 25)
                    || (LOWER_BEGIN_UTF8 <= charCode && charCode <= LOWER_BEGIN_UTF8 + 25)
                    || str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '_' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '~'){
                    out << str[i];
                }
                else {
                    out << '%' << hex << uppercase << charCode;
                }
            }
            encoded = out.str();
            return encoded;
        }
    }

    namespace Twitter {
        namespace OAuth {
            static string CreateData(vector<string>const OAuth, METHOD method, int Start) {
                string query;
                for (int t = Start; t < OAuth.size(); t++) {
                    if (t != Start)query += "&";
                    query += OAuth[t];
                }
                return query;
            }

            static int split_url(const string url, vector<string>* OAuth) {
                int num = url.find_first_of('?');
                OAuth->push_back(url.substr(0, num));
                OAuth->push_back(url.substr(num + 1));
                return 0;
            }

            static string sha1(const string Key, const string Data) {
                char* key = (char*)Key.c_str();
                char* data = (char*)Data.c_str();
                unsigned char res[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1];
                size_t reslen;

                HMAC(EVP_sha1(), key, strlen(key), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data), strlen(data), res, &reslen);

                return string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(res), reslen);
            }

            static int encode_base64(char* bufin, int len, char* bufout){
                static unsigned char base64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
                unsigned char* pin = (unsigned char*)bufin;
                unsigned char* pout = (unsigned char*)bufout;

                for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 3){
                    *pout++ = base64[pin[0] >> 2];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & ((pin[0] << 4) | (pin[1] >> 4))];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & ((pin[1] << 2) | (pin[2] >> 6))];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & pin[2]];
                    pin += 3;
                }
                if (len % 3 == 1){
                    *pout++ = base64[pin[0] >> 2];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & (pin[0] << 4)];
                    *pout++ = '=';
                    *pout++ = '=';
                }
                else if (len % 3 == 2){
                    *pout++ = base64[pin[0] >> 2];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & ((pin[0] << 4) | (pin[1] >> 4))];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & (pin[1] << 2)];
                    *pout++ = '=';
                }
                *pout = '\0';
                return pout - (unsigned char*)bufout;
            }

            static string CreateSignature(string ConsumerSecret, string AccessSecret, vector<string>const& OAuth, METHOD method, int Start = 1) {
                string str, key, data, methods;
                char out[256];

                if (method == POST)methods = "POST";
                else methods = "GET";

                key = ConsumerSecret + "&" + AccessSecret;

                data = methods + "&" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(OAuth[0]) + "&" + CreateData(OAuth, method, Start);

                str = sha1(key, data);

                CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::encode_base64((char*)str.c_str(), sizeof(str) - 1, out);

                return out;
            }

            static int IntOAuthParams(vector<string>* OAuth, METHOD method) {
                TwitterAPI_Keys key;

                auto CreateNonce = []() {
                    static const char* chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_";
                    const unsigned int max = 26 + 26 + 10 + 1;
                    char tmp[50];
                    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
                    int len = 15 + rand() % 16;
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        tmp[i] = chars[rand() % max];
                    }
                    return std::string(tmp, len);
                };

                string oauth_nonce = "oauth_nonce";
                oauth_nonce += "=";
                oauth_nonce += CreateNonce();
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_nonce);

                string oauth_timestamp = "oauth_timestamp";
                oauth_timestamp += "=";
                oauth_timestamp += to_string((int)time(nullptr));
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_timestamp);

                string oauth_token = "oauth_token";
                oauth_token += "=";
                oauth_token += key.Accesstoken;
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_token);

                string oauth_consumer_key = "oauth_consumer_key";
                oauth_consumer_key += "=";
                oauth_consumer_key += key.Consumer_Key;
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_consumer_key);

                string oauth_signature_method = "oauth_signature_method";
                oauth_signature_method += "=";
                oauth_signature_method += "HMAC-SHA1";
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_signature_method);

                string oauth_version = "oauth_version";
                oauth_version += "=";
                oauth_version += "1.0";
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_version);

                sort(OAuth->begin() + 1, OAuth->end());

                string oauth_signature = "oauth_signature";
                oauth_signature += "=";
                oauth_signature += CreateSignature(key.Consumer_Sec, key.Accesstoken_Aec, *OAuth, method);
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_signature);

                return 0;
            }

            static Request OAuthAuthentication(string url, METHOD method) {
                vector<string> OAuth;

                split_url(url, &OAuth);

                CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::IntOAuthParams(&OAuth, method);

                Request req;

                if (method == POST) {
                    req.url = OAuth[0];
                    req.post = CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::CreateData(OAuth, method, 1);
                }
                else {
                    req.url = OAuth[0];
                    req.post = CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::CreateData(OAuth, method, 1);
                }

                return req;
            }
        }

        static string tweet(string message) {
            message = CAIOS::String::SJIS_to_UTF8(message);

            string url = TWITTER_URL;
            url += "?status=" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(message);

            Request req = OAuth::OAuthAuthentication(url, POST);
            return CAIOS::REST::POST(req);
        }
    }
}
```

**補足**
Authorizationヘッダが必要な場合、どのようにヘッダをつければいいのでしょうか。TwitterではAuthorizationヘッダが必要でない場合と必要な場合？の２つがあるようですが、このときは必要。このときは不要などのラインを教えてくださるとありがたいです。

Comment: 質問したまま放置するのではなく解決したのであれば承認を、解決していないのであれば何を求めているのか補足をしてください。

Comment: 修正させていただきました。大変申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HMAC-SHA1署名する対象のデータは、

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXX（略）
```

のような文字列になりますが、ここが少し違います。

「`oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXX`」この部分はURLエンコードされている必要があります。正しくは、「`oauth_consumer_key%3DXXXXXX`」とします。

そのため、`CreateSignature`関数で`data`を組み立てる処理を修正します。

【修正前】

```
data = methods + "&" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(OAuth[0]) + "&" + CreateData(OAuth, method, Start);
```

【修正後】

```
data = methods + "&" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(OAuth[0]) + "&" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(CreateData(OAuth, method, Start));
```

---

`std::string`オブジェクトに対して`sizeof()`は間違いです。`size()`関数で長さを取得します。（ちなみに、この値は常に20のはずです。）

【修正前】

```
CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::encode_base64((char*)str.c_str(), sizeof(str) - 1, out);
```

【修正後】

```
CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::encode_base64((char*)str.c_str(), str.size(), out);
```

---

HMAC-SHA1署名後のBASE64文字列をURLエンコードする必要があります。

【修正前】

```
return out;
```

【修正後】

```
return CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(out);
```

---

以上の修正でデータは正しくなると思いますが、気になる点を。

HMAC-SHA1署名する関数で、「`HMAC(EVP_sha1(), ～～～（略）`」となっているところ、この関数は、20バイトのバイナリデータを返します。そのすぐ下で「`return string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(res), reslen);`」となっていますが、バイナリデータを`std::string`に格納するのは良くないです。`char *out`や`std::vector<char> *out`などに格納するか、この関数内でBASE64化した文字列を作って返すのがいいでしょう。

あと、Authorizationヘッダについてですが、テキストのツイート（`x-www-form-urlencoded`でPOST）するには、このヘッダはいりません。画像などをアップロード（`multipart/form-data`でPOST）する際Authorizationヘッダが必要になります。

---

【追記】（画像アップロード機能）

メディア（画像など）添付のツイートをするには、先にファイルをアップロードします。

拙作twicppsでは、 https://github.com/soramimi/twicpps/blob/master/src/tweet.cpp の92行目以降でファイルのPOSTの処理を行っています。APIは`https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json`です。前述の通り`multipart/form-data`でのPOSTです。アップロードに成功するとJSONデータが返りますので、そこから`media_id`の値を取り出します。

アップロードが完了したら、本文のツイートですが、その際に`media_ids`というパラメータを追加してPOSTします。

私のプログラムではJSONパーサまで自作していますが、代わりにpicojsonなどを利用してみるのもいいかと思います。

Comment: soramimiさん本人から回答をいただけるなんて非常に光栄です...! 指摘していただいたところを改善し、POSTのbodyにパラメータを入れてPOSTすることで、無事ツイートができました。ありがとうございます。今後、画像などもPOSTする予定なのですが、Authorizationヘッダについて詳しく教えていただけませんか？TwicppsではRequestOptionにURLとdataだけ載せてPOSTしているようですが...（見落としでしたらすみません）

Answer (score 1):

あまりに迷走しているようなので、cpprestsdkだけを使ってTwitter Timelineを取得するサンプルを書いてみました。参考にしてください。

Visual Studioを使用している場合は、プロジェクトにNugetパッケージ[cpprestsdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk)を追加するだけです。（OpenSSLやboostは必要ありません。）

```
#include <locale>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/oauth1.h>

static constexpr auto
    apikey = U(""),
    apisecretkey = U(""),
    accesstoken = U(""),
    accesstokensecret = U("");

int wmain() {
    // コンソールに日本語を表示するための設定
    _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"");

    web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_config oauth1_config{
        apikey,
        apisecretkey,
        U("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
        U("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
        U("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
        U(""),
        web::http::oauth1::experimental::oauth1_methods::hmac_sha1
    };
    oauth1_config.set_token({ accesstoken, accesstokensecret });
    web::http::client::http_client_config http_client_config;
    http_client_config.set_oauth1(oauth1_config);
    web::http::client::http_client api{ U("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"), http_client_config };

    auto timeline = api.request(web::http::methods::GET, U("statuses/home_timeline.json")).get().extract_json().get();
    for (auto const& status : timeline.as_array())
        ucout << status.as_object().at(U("text")).as_string() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: サンプルまで作って頂き、ありがとうございます。
VisualStudip2019で実行しましたが、26行目（http_client_config.set_oauth1(oauth1_config);）でハンドルされていない例外が投げられています。このプログラムはAuthorizationヘッダを作成していないようですが、タイムラインの取得はヘッダ無しでできるのでしょうか？

Comment: @松本大智 当方では動作確認済みですので、例外の内容が分からないことには原因は分かりません。Authorizationヘッダは[この辺り](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/57a7ff2c0720d38bd1384c2b0b09c17a549fcbe4/Release/src/http/oauth/oauth1.cpp#L331-L384)で生成していますが、どう確認されたのでしょうか？